# How to immediately know that data in textarea has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I making a page with a textarea that user can change.

What is the best way to know that user is done entering data in it and i can send contents of it?

I have tried using jQuery .change() function, but i found it a bit unreliable, since it triggers only after user clicks on something after he is done entering data(so there is a few cases when entered data will not be registered (like if user presses F5)

Comment: What about `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup` events?

Comment: how would you like to explain _done entering_ ?? `tab out`, hit `Enter`???

Comment: Regent, thanks - that's not a bad idea.

Comment: Guruprasad Rao, when user stops entering for a certain amount of time or clicks somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know when a user is done with a field, try `focusOut()`.

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element
>   inside of it, loses focus.

Try entering any random word or sentence into the field, then click outside of the textarea and see what happens.

```js
$('#textarea1').focusout(function(){
  //Your action code goes here!
  alert($('#textarea1').val());
});
```

```css
#textarea1 {
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
```

**EDIT:** Whoops, that's the same issue as what OP tried to get around. So `keyup()` will do then.

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on
>   the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only
>   sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can vary
>   between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

```js
$('#textarea1').keyup(function(){
  //Your action code goes here!
  $('#textval').text($('#textarea1').val());
});
```

```css
#textarea1 {
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>

<div id="finalval">The value is <span id="textval">unset</span></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't it have the same problem as change()?

Comment: @Deniss Whoops, my bad. Edited it and added a better example that _does_ answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)? But I doubt you can exactly determin the user to be finished entering data and at the same time prevent him from leaving the side (or reload) without saving the input data.

You could use keyboard events to save the data in storage and reload the data after reloading the page. But I would not do that for sending the data to a server. It would be a huge traffic source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input` event, if you want to fire it on each key press. It's often used in autocompletes, etc..

```
$(document).on('input', '#yourElement', function () {
    console.log("Input has changed!");
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/n5smp9pa/)